# How to write a list as separate elements using csv?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have two lists that look like this:

```
list1 = ['filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3']
list2 = ['1', '2', ['3', '4', '5']]
```

How can I write to a csv file that will end up like this?

```
filename1,1
filename2,2
filename3,3,4,5
```

I've tried two things but neither work:

```
with open(outfname, 'wb') as fout:
        csv_out = csv.writer(fout)
        csv_out.writerows(izip(list1, list2))
```

This shows:

```
filename1,['1']
filename2,['2']
filename3,['3','4','5']
```

I tried adding this prior to writerows:

```
",".join(list2)
```

But the results will show:

```
filename1,1
filename2,2
filename3,"1,2,3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Satya has a good idea to use pandas but you need to flatten list2, you can do that with `.apply()`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import sys
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'list1': list1, 'list2': list2})
>>> df = df.join(df.list2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)))
>>> df.drop('list2', axis=1).to_csv(sys.stdout, header=False, index=False)
filename1,1,,
filename2,2,,
filename3,3,4,5
```

This puts empty fields where there is missing data.
Alternatively you can write your own special zip:

```
def my_zip(l1, l2):
    for a, b in zip(l1, l2):
        try:
            yield [a]+b
        except TypeError:
            yield [a, b]

>>> csv_out = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
>>> csv_out.writerows(my_zip(list1, list2))
filename1,1
filename2,2
filename3,3,4,5
```

Which is exactly the output requested.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas data-frame instead to form the desired .csv file

```
import pandas as pd
list1 = ['filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3']
list2 = ['1', '2', ['3', '4', '5']]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = list1
df['b'] = list2
df.to_csv('D:/sx.csv',index=False) ####you can give any desired path for csv
```

TO FLATTEN the list just do

```
df['b']=[','.join(x) for x in df['b']]  ####i have separated the list items by comma as of now, but you can give your own separator
```

continuing the code

```
  df.to_csv('D:/sx.csv',index=False)
  d = pd.read_csv('D:/sx.csv')
  d 
       a      b
 0  filename1      1
 1  filename2      2
 2  filename3  3,4,5
```

Again modifying

```
  d['a'] = d['a']+','+d['b']
  d
  Out[39]: 
             a      b
0      filename1,1      1
1      filename2,2      2
2  filename3,3,4,5  3,4,5
```

then drop the column b

```
 df = d.drop('b',axis=1)
 df
Out[44]: 
             a
 0      filename1,1
 1      filename2,2
 2  filename3,3,4,5
 ######column a shows the desired output...
```

now you can form the csv by df.to_csv('path+file.csv')

Comment: This still doesn't flatten `list[2]`.

Comment: That would still put delimiters around the field which the OP was trying to avoid, see the last example output.

Comment: @AChampion-may be i misinterpreted the OP's question..the columns need to be zipped.

Comment: If you replace `'D:/sx.csv'` with `sys.stdout` (or look at the file created) you would see `3,4,5` is delimiter `"3,4,5"`. When you read it back it pandas strips the delimeters.

Answer (score 0):

Like this. It requires a few temporary lists, but gets the job done.

```
import csv

list1 = ['filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3']
list2 = ['1', '2', ['3', '4', '5']]

with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    r = csv.writer(f)
    for name, num in zip(list1, list2):
        r.writerow([name] + list(num))
```

`out.csv` looks like

```
filename1,1
filename2,2
filename3,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need pandas for that. First to get your desired data structure you can just use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). To save to CSV you can use standard CSV module.

```
import csv
list1 = ['filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3']
list2 = ['1', '2', ['3', '4', '5']]

zipped = zip(list1, list2)
with open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerows(zipped)
```

Comment: Did you try this? This is not what the OP was looking for, and they had already tried `[i]zip`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a string is a one item list. Why do you need pandas and all for this simple task?

```
list1 = ['filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3']
list2 = ['1', '2', ['3', '4', '5']]
with open(outfname, 'w') as fout:
    for item in zip(list1,list2):
        fout.write(item[0])
        fout.write(',')
        fout.write(','.join(item[1]))
        fout.write('\n')
```

Comment: This is native. No modules imported. Super trivial folks!

Comment: Works for the example input but is a bit limited, any non-nested 2 digit number (e.g. `['11','22',['3','4','5']]`) would also get a `','` put between the digits.